# Adding video thumbnail in the app causes lag

Tags: java, android

I am working on a video player app but when add a video thumbnail in the app, it becomes laggy.

**here is my code**

videofielAdapter.java

```
 Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoList.get(position).getPath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
        holder.VideoThumb.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

MainActivity.java

```
 private ArrayList<Videos_Models>LoadVideos(Context context) {
        ArrayList<Videos_Models> TempList = new ArrayList<>();

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String [] projection = {
                MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,


        };

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        if (cursor!= null){
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){


                String id =cursor.getString(0);
                String path =cursor.getString(1);
                String title =cursor.getString(2);
                String fileName =cursor.getString(3);
                String size =cursor.getString(4);
                String dateAdded =cursor.getString(5);
                String duration =cursor.getString(6);
             }
         }
     }
```